# How to change UWP checkbox text color

Tags: checkbox, uwp

I want to change the checkbox text color dynamically in UWP when the checkbox is checked. If I didn't give any color then it should take the default color based on theme. I tried the below code but it does not work.

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
        }
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Regards,
Sarath

Answer (score 0):

You can use CheckBox Styles/Template to modify it as per your need.
Refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx

You will need to modify this :

```
<FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph"
              FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
              Glyph="&#xE001;"
              FontSize="20"
              Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}"
              Opacity="0" />
```

Comment: The user asked to change the text color and did not specify that they wanted the checkmark to change. They also asked to do it dynamically when the checkbox is checked and we should assume that unchecking the checkbox should also change the color back to some original value. This answer does not satisfy any of those things.